# cloudfoundry and geronimo app

Tags: cloud-foundry, geronimo

I'm planning to deploy geronimo based java app on CloudFoundry. I read the documentation that CloudFoundry assigns a port per application. Geronimo app have port numbers for app, admin and jmx monitoring.

is there any way we can request cloudfoundry to assign more than one port to each application and we can use these ports in different config in the codebase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First just fyi, if you are deploying the app as a Java web app, CloudFoundry in the backend uses only Tomcat as the application server. Therefore for your case you need to deploy it as a standalone app with your own Geronimo runtime. http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/05/11/running-standalone-web-applications-on-cloud-foundry/

CF apps get one IP and one port each, accessible via environment variables VCAP_APP_HOST and VCAP_APP_PORT. There isnt a way to assign explicitly. Ports an app listens to other than the port assigned will not be accessible through CF router.

If you are interested, my suggestion would be deploying multiple apps for each port(Geronimo function) you want to listen to. This would give you URL-based app, admin or jmx monitoring.